# закрыть balloon yandexmap

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Всем привет, пытаюсь закрыть по событию клика по метке балун, но он совсем не хочет закрываться.
Если я оставлю setTimeout(function () { myMap.balloon.close(); }, 3000); то все нормально отрабатывает, но мне не подходит через таймаут, еще если использовать команду myMap.balloon.events.close(); , то свою задачу она выполнит, но браузер будет говорить про ошибку placemark_layout.js:6718 Uncaught TypeError: myMap.balloon.events.close is not a function.
Что я делаю не так?
https://jsfiddle.net/bgrm497t/

```
    InstDriverCollection.events.add('click', function (e) {
       // setTimeout(function () { myMap.balloon.close(); }, 3000);
       myMap.balloon.close();
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы по клику на метку балун закрывался, нужно отказаться от стандартного поведения балуна и управлять балуном самостоятельно.

Для этого добавляем в опции метки флаги:

```
    preset: 'islands#blueCircleDotIcon', // чтобы метка не загораживалась балуном
    openBalloonOnClick: false // чтобы балун не открывался самостоятельно
```

и добавляем обработку события:

```
    mark.events.add('click', function (e) {
      let balloon = myMap.balloon;
      if (balloon.isOpen()) {
        balloon.close();
      } else {
        let data = mark.properties.get('balloonContent');
        let coords = mark.geometry.getCoordinates();
        balloon.open(coords,data);
      }
    })
```

Ещё перед закрытием балуна можно добавить проверку, что балун имеет те же координаты и содержимое, что и метка.

Comment: понял, спасибо, но почему тогда setTimeout(function () { myMap.balloon.close(); }, 3000);  - работает, а если я вызываю функцию myMap.balloon.close()  без таймаут, то не срабатывает? , не успевает еще к тому моменту открыться?

Comment: Стандартное поведение - балун тут же опять открывается по клику.